# Changing slug as subdomain on htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, slug

I have some problem on changing the slug url as subdomain

the example

```
domain.com/manifest
```

So i want to everyone can access on subdomain taken from slug with all assets on that slug

```
manifest.domain.com
```

Im working on htacess, is possible to do that ?

Comment: This isn't something you would do in `.htaccess` (except to perhaps redirect from the old to new URL). Have you already created the subdomain (in the DNS and server config) that points to the appropriate filesystem location (ie. the `manifest` subdirectory)? What problem are you having specifically? As for changing the URL - you do that in WordPress.